# How do I set up an end-to-end test in python spanning multiple repositories without introducing circular dependencies?

Tags: python

my team and I work on a large python codebase with multiple repositories, each one containing the code for a separate service. For simplicity, let's say these repositories are called `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

Recently we have been focused on writing tests to mimic the end-to-end workflow of a user, which spans across all of these repositories. The initial way we had written these tests were as follows:

- Create a new repository called `testing` for the end to end tests.
- Import all the relevant modules from `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.
- Use those modules to stitch together an e2e test using `pytest`.
- Integrate these tests into our CI system for `foo`, `bar` and `baz` such that if anything in these repos breaks the e2e tests, then we stop the push.

  - Within `foo`, we have tests written by importing some functions from the `testing` repo which allow us to define e2e tests.

The problem we are running into right now is that we are having problems integrating the tests into the CI system for `foo`. This is what the CI system looks like when there's change:

- Check out the latest code from `main`
- Install via `pip install .` (using `setup.py` - migration to `pyproject.toml` is planned)
- Run `python -m pytest tests/`

We're failing at the `pip install .` step because of circular dependencies causing a `ResolutionImpossible` error.

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested foo 0.1 (from ***)
    testing 0.1 depends on foo 0.1 (from ***)
```

What is the canonical way to set up these kinds of tests without causing circular dependencies? Any tips or pointers to more detailed reference guides would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Within foo, we have tests written by importing some functions from the testing repo which allow us to define e2e tests.` Can you disentangle the methods used by both `tests` and `foo` into their own "common" repo? Failing that, can you separate the foo tests out from foo? Or are there bi-directional dependencies there too?

Comment: Separating the common methods into a separate repo would be very hard for us to do. And we have considered just separating the `foo` tests into `foo`, but it wouldn't be a true end-to-end test in that case anymore.